# IF, IFF and CASE WHEN not working in query

Tags: sql-server

I cannot get the following to work:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
         Items.ItemCode,
         ItemAccounts.ItemCodeAccount,
         ItemAccounts.PurchasePrice,
         ItemAccounts.PurchaseCurrency
       --CASE WHEN  ItemAccounts.PurchaseCurrency = 'EUR' , '1' , '2' AS sdfsdfsdf,
       --IFF ItemAccounts.PurchaseCurrency = 'EUR' , '1' , '2' AS sdfsdfsdf,
       --IF ItemAccounts.PurchaseCurrency = 'EUR' , '1' , '2' AS sdfsdfsdf
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN ItemAccounts ON Items.Itemcode=ItemAccounts.ItemCode
```

The IF, IFF and CASE WHEN statements are not working in the query. Based on everything I've found at least one of the three should be working.

I'm working with SQL Server Management Studio v 15.0.18338.0

Comment: What is IFF supposed to mean?  How does it differ from IF?

Answer (score 3):

SQL-Server <> MySQL. These are two completely different databases!

```sql
CASE
    WHEN ItemAccounts.PurchaseCurrency = 'EUR' THEN '1'
    ELSE '2'
END AS sdfsdfsdf
```

See:

- [MySQL CASE Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)
- [SQL CASE Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Fortunately the CASE expression is the same in both of them. But this is not the case for many other features.

Comment: `IIF` does exist in SQL Server it's just a function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It appeared I forgot the 'END' statement. All makes sense now. Thank you very much sir!!

Comment: ... and the `THEN` and `ELSE` as well.